# Optimize loop around a get and function call using returned value?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, temporary

Here is a fragment getting data from a buffered source and sending it along to be processed. If the queue is empty, get() returns a null, and the process method is happy to take a null and do nothing.
What is the most optimum way to code this?

```
something a; // any legal C++ return type...
aQueueOfSomethings g;

while (true) { 
    a=g.get();
    process(a);
}
```

There is no way to predict the values arriving via get(), they are what they are, and they need to be dequeued and passed on to process() as quickly as possible.

I don't see a lot of wasted effort here- if I skip the explicit local variable named 'a' and make the loop a one liner:

```
    process(g.get());
```

the implicit return value of g.get() will still have space allocated, might involve a constructor call, etc, etc.

If the thing returned has any size or complexity, it would be better to have a pointer to it rather than a copy of it, and pass that pointer rather than a copy by value...  So I'd prefer to have

```
something *a;

    g.get(a);
    process(a);
```

rather than

```
 something a;

    a=g.get();
    process(a);
```

I wrote a test case in c++ trying the two line and one line versions, loop 100,000,000 times.

If the a is an object with 4 integer and 2 floating point numbers, and the process() method touches them all, the two line solution is actually faster! If the a object is a single int, the one-line version is faster. If the object is complex but the process() method just touches one value, the one-line version is faster.

Most interesting to me, using g++ compiler, Mac OS X 10.5.8, the -O first level optimization switch results in identical, much faster, operation, with both 1 and 2 line versions.

Other than letting the compiler optimize, a single line for both methods and no explicit intermediate variable, and pass by reference so avoiding making copies, is there anything that would generally make it run faster? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: "Ah, motivation!?"  Glad you asked. This was an interview question, and having gotten down to the 2 line form, I said I thought we were done. The person I was speaking with was very surprised and said, firmly, that I was missing something. Something so obvious that she wouldn't tell me what it was, I should think about it. So I have. (Obviously I failed to impress and am no longer a candidate for that job...) That's why I was wondering about the one line version- and why I made and measured test cases. Optimization moots it. Perhaps she meant me to change the interface to pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a supreme case of useless optimization

(you are taking something that buffers *and* want to bit-optimize it?)

Also, the compiler will compile both ways to exactly the same code, and (in most circumstances) is completely entitled to do return value optimization *and* tail call optimization.

Combined with probable inlining of queue_class::get() your issue seems to be completely MOOT

Answer (score 3):

I believe your are trying to beat the compiler at his own job.

Have you experienced performance issues ? If not, you might focus on producing a readable code (which you seem to have) that you can maintain rather than resorting to what could be premature optimization and clutter the code with weird optimizations.

Comment: That was my take too. I'm glad to read that others see it that way!

Answer (score 2):

The issue with this code is not in what you've done, but in that it has to spin - **wasting CPU** cycles that some other task your computer's performing might have used - even when there's no work to do.

If there are many programs that take this attitude (that they're king of the computer and will hog entire CPUs) then everything slows to an absolute crawl.  It's a very drastic decision to let your code work like this.

If possible, change the entire model so that you get a **callback/signal/event** of some kind when there's more data available.

Comment: +1 exactly. I was going to suggest that the obvious way to speed this loop up would be to parallelize it. I'm pretty sure that's not what the original question meant, of course.

Comment: Joseph, you're clearly correct, I hadn't thought of that. The stated problem is that performance of this loop is the be all and end all, but its worth noting the waste of computes. The explanation was so long as it was, I didn't want to add more to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you should let the compiler optimise, but if you know that it is safe to do this:

```
while (true) { 
    a=g.get();
    b=g.get();
    c=g.get();
    d=g.get();
    process(a);
    process(b);
    process(c);
    process(d);
}
```

then it might make things faster.

Or, even more extreme, get a whole array of the return type (or pointers to it) ready, then loop over it processing them. If process() and get() both use a lot of code, then doing this could mean all the code can stay in immediate cache, instead of being fetched from a further cache each time the function is called.

The compiler can't make this optimisation because it probably doesn't know that it's safe to re-order function calls.

Comment: That might (always benchmark if you care) help throughput if there's a backlog of data to handle, but will *increase* latency when only the first `get()` returns data....

Comment: Yes, always benchmark :) True: it's optimising for throughput not latency.

Comment: +1 for creative thinking; too bad it's probably academic in this case :)

Comment: This might pay off- Going bang-bang between two different pieces of code can be slower than going through a number of calls to one piece and a number of calls to another piece.   It also occurs to me, belatedly, that multi-threading with one thread reading g.get() and one thread processing(), with one variable for each, would be very likely to run faster than a single-thread in sequence. Then there are  FIFo-buffered queues... Maximum flow, not shortest transmission time, was the stated objective.